# VBA for cut Data for certain Keywords

Tags: vba, excel

I want cut data from A1:D10000 for certain keyword. Example if have any string with "Release Date:\n "it will be cut & paste in corresponding cell in F column. 
I mean if any string have with "Release Date:\n " in C21 then it will be cut & paste in F21

I have a code & it works fine. But problem is it needs huge time to complete than i expected. Any better code as if it runs quickly?

My Code:

Sub Macro87()

```
For Repeat = 1 To 10000
Dim found As Range
Sheets("part15").Select
Range("A1").Select
Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.Select
Set found = Selection.Find(What:="Release Date:\n ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
    , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
found.Select
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Cut
 Range("F" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Set found = Nothing
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to stop using `select`, you can say `found.cut` for example `Range("F" & (ActiveCell.Row)).value=found.value`  also turn off calculation whilst processing.   Also perhaps use a string comparison function, like instr, to do what you want. You can also use SEARCH & FIND in a formula, so you could add the formula like this =IF(ISERR(SEARCH("release date\n",I1)),"",I1) and then search the results column in your loop looking for non "" entries

Comment: I'd think InStr would be faster to loop through with.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave mentioned, much of your slow down is going to come from the repeated select statements in your code. VBA usually does not need to select a range in order to work with the data therein. The following should speed things up for you quite a bit. It runs for me instantaneously:

```
Sub Macro87()
    Set Rng = Range("A1:D10000")
    For Each cel In Rng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Release Date:\n ") > 0 Then
            Cells(cel.Row(), 6) = cel.Value
            cel.Value = Empty
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: String can found anywhere in Range A1:D10000. I mean it can found in b12 or c15 or d11. Always it needs go to in Column F

Comment: @Hafigur Yup. Just saw that. Made the change. Sorry about that.

Comment: Another important matter that string are not only "Release Date:\n" String may have other data with "Release Date:\n " I mean "Release Date:\n "  is a keyword in a string.

Comment: @Hafigur Right, the above code will copy any cell containing "Release Date:\n " even if there's other data in there. Should work just fine. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I tried several times Code runs but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Hafigur Are you sure that there's a space in your string after "Release Date:\n "? Works fine on my end.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, stop going from 1 to 10,000 - you don't need to repeat the action so much when you can use .FindNext instead.  Secondly, avoid like the plague the use of `.Select`.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("part15")
Dim lastRow
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim found As Range
With ws.Range("A:D")
    Set found = .Find(What:="Release Date:\n ", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext _
    , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = found.Address
        Do
            ws.Range("F" & found.Row).Value = found.Value
            set found = .FindNext(found)
        Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Run Time error 91for this line   Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> firstAddress

Comment: RT91 means an object variable is not set - Did you miss a `Set` statement in the line above where the error is triggered?

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong; try stepping through the code using the F8 key and see what `found.Address` is when it hits the `Loop While...` line?